# How to create Final Cut Pro files on Windows machine?

Tags: file-formats, final-cut-pro

I need to edit some video files and submit my work as FCP7 XML file (XMEML). In which software it can be done? I don't need any special and exotic features, I need only file cutting.

Only one thing I need: it must work on WindowsXP or Windows 7 (XP is better). Maybe exists something small, what can run on old machine?

Answer (score 2):

If you have, or can rent Adobe Premiere you can [export as FCP XML](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/exporting-projects-applications.html#export_a_final_cut_pro_project_xml_file) from that. Davinci Resolve [does too](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10283/fcpx-davinci-resolve-fcpx-color-grading-round-trip), but I'm not sure if the capability is included in the free version.

Comment: Both applications are 64-bits only, it will not work on old computer

Comment: Another format you could use is an EDL (edit decision list). These files have existed since video editing was done on tape, and FCP can still import them. You can create them in a text editor if you have to.

Comment: I know about EDL, but requirement is FCP/FC7

Answer (score 1):

A company called [Automatic Duck](http://www.automaticduck.com) used to make several products for converting between Final Cut Pro 7, Adobe Premiere Pro, Adobe After Effects, and Avid. They no longer sell those products since FCP7 was end-of-lifed 6+ years ago. But you might be able to find an editor who has an old copy they can lend you.

Alternatively, the FCP7 XML file format was [fairly well documented](https://documentation.apple.com/en/finalcutpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=97%26section=3%26tasks=true). If all you need are cuts, you might be able to create one by hand in a text editor.